# How can I assign div’s HTML to a title attribute of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image with the following HTML:

```
<img id='ToolTipImage' class='tooltip' src='/files/404048/93171/Info-32.png' title='' style='margin-top:3px; margin-left:4px;' />
<div id='AssessmentsGrid'> </div>
```

I am using tipTip as a tooltip and want to assign div (AssessmentsGrid)’s html to the title attribute of my image above. Initially div (AssessmentsGrid) is empty and then I run a query and populate it.

Comment: classical case of give me the codez plz? This is just some basic stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I missing something?

> ```
> <div id='AssessmentsGrid'><span>test</span></div>
> ```

```
$("#ToolTipImage").attr('title', $("#AssessmentsGrid").html());
```

now the img has the title

```
<span>test</span>
```

??

[image]

Comment: A `title` attribute cannot contain HTML, for this you really should use the `text()` method rather than `html()`.

Comment: Well, "cant" is a big word- when it actually **can** ... See update.

Comment: Sad that a 84000-guy cannot distinguish between text and HTML markup, and claim rubbish without testing it. The title `<span>test</span>` is **not** HTML, it is text!

Comment: Yes, that would be text; as opposed to HTML. Your point was..?

Comment: that the above do the job, and you mislead people by your comment

Answer (score 0):

So if i understand you correctly you want to fill the title attr of the image with the contents of the div. Correct?

If so you could do something like this:

```
 var divText = $("#AssesmentsGrid").text();
 $("#ToolTipImage").attr("title",divText);
```

Comment: That will only transfer the text portion, eg `test` of `<span>test</span>`

Comment: Yup, why would you want a span in there? Thanks btw Muhammand :)

Comment: @Vpml - Because thats the question...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ToolTipImage").hover(function(){
        $(this).attr('title', $("#AssessmentsGrid").text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a= $("#AssessmentsGrid"), b = $("#ToolTipImage");

b.attr('title', a.text());
```

This is more appropriate

and to use javascript only...

```
var 
$0= document.getElementById('ToolTipImage'), $1= document.getElementById('AssessmentsGrid').innerText;
$0.setAttribute('title',$1);
```